# How to execute a root command using Python's pexpect library?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pexpect

I am trying to mount a drives shared folder on my system (Centos).

Since the `mount` command needs to be executed as a root user, I am first logging in as sudo user using the `su` command. After the login is successful, I want to execute my mount command.

```
import pexpect

cmd1 = "su"
cmd2 = "mount -t cifs -o username=abc,password=def //101.101.101.214/Volume1 /home/Juna/Drive"
pwd = "my_password"
child = pexpect.spawn(cmd1)
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline(pwd)
child.expect('#')
child.sendline(cmd2)
```

I am not getting the desired results from my script. Can you please share what needs to be done or modified in my script to get the desired result.

Comment: It's really better to give the user doing this [`NOPASSWD` sudo access](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18830/45416) than to put your root password into the Python script.  It's likely to leak from that script (eg if you eventually push this to github), and it makes the invocation more complex.

Comment: Don't just say "I am not getting the desired result", say what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than sending the command interactively, use the [`-c` option to `su`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) to give it the command you want to run:

```
child = pexpect.spawn(['su', 'root', '-c', cmd2])
```